# I've been running this code monthly for over a year, but for some reason am just now getting this SQL group by/aggregate error

Tags: t-sql, group-by, aggregate

I've run this code regularly for awhile without any error, but am suddenly seeing this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 95
> Column '#CampaignHistory.MaturityDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 96
> Column '#CampaignHistory.MaturityDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Here's the code I'm using.  Everything above this code runs fine w/o errors:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MaturityDate <= '2021-01-31' THEN 'Closed'
                    WHEN MaturityDate >= '2021-02-01' THEN 'Active' END AS Campaign,
             COUNT (DISTINCT CustomerID) AS Peeps
       FROM #CampaignHistory
GROUP BY CASE WHEN MaturityDate <= '2020-01-31' THEN 'Closed'
                    WHEN MaturityDate >= '2021-02-01' THEN 'Active' END;
```

[image: image of code and error]

Comment: @KenWhite: CASE expressions are allowed in the GROUP BY clause, but aliases are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions in the SELECT clause and the GROUP BY clause are different: the first one mentions 2021-01-31, the second one mentions 2020-01-31.

To avoid duplicating the code and to prevent such typos, you can use one of the following queries:

```
SELECT Campaign, COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) AS Peeps
FROM (
    SELECT CustomerID,
        CASE
            WHEN MaturityDate <= '2021-01-31' THEN 'Closed'
            WHEN MaturityDate >= '2021-02-01' THEN 'Active'
        END AS Campaign
    FROM #CampaignHistory
) x GROUP BY Campaign
```

or

```
SELECT      Campaign, COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) AS Peeps
FROM        #CampaignHistory
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT  CASE
                WHEN MaturityDate <= '2021-01-31' THEN 'Closed'
                WHEN MaturityDate >= '2021-02-01' THEN 'Active'
            END AS Campaign
) x
GROUP BY x.Campaign
```

Comment: or declare 2 variables